# How to write test cases in `ava` for below code snippet

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const Duration = minutes => {
    const oneMinute = 1;
    const minutesInAnHour = 60;
    if (minutes <= oneMinute) {
        return  "in just 1 minute";
    }  
    if (minutes < minutesInOneHour) {
        return  "in just" + " " + minutes.toFixed(0) + " " + "minutes";
    }
    if (minutes === minutesInOneHour) {
        return  "in just 1 hour.";
    } 
    const hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    const minutesValue = Math.ceil(minutes % 60);
    const hourString = hours === 1 ? "hour" : "hours";
    const minuteString = minutesValue === 1 ? `1 min` : minutesValue > 0 ? `${minutesValue.toFixed(0)} mins` : "";
    return `${hours} ${hourString}${minuteString ? ` ${minuteString}` : ""}`;

} module.exports = { Duration }
```

I am new to writing test cases in ava. Above is a code snippet for example. How can we write test cases in ava for this.

Comment: AVA assumes you are using ESM (ECMAScript modules). Since you are using CJS (CommonJS) i.e. `module.exports`, I don't think you can use AVA.

Answer (score 0):

AVA assumes you are using ESM (ECMAScript modules); see: [*"Create your test file"*](https://github.com/avajs/ava#create-your-test-file).

**Note:** You have a typo. Change all occurrences of `minutesInOneHour` to `minutesInAnHour`.

---

First, you will need to install `ava`.

```bash
npm i -D ava     # or
yarn add -D ava
```

Next, you need to add a test `script` to your `package.json`.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "ava"
  }
}
```

Now, create a test file that ends in `.test.js` e.g. `Time.test.js`. These tests should be placed in a directory called `__tests__`. This is the standard when it comes to JavaScript unit tests.

Here is an example tree of a project:

```
+ project/
  + dist/
    - index.css
    - index.html
    - index.js
  + node_modules/
    > ...
  + src/
    + __tests__
      + Time.test.mjs
    + main.js
    + Time.mjs
  - package.json
```

### `src/__tests__/Time.test.mjs`

```js
import test from "ava";

import { Duration } from "../Time.mjs";

test("Test Duration valid", (t) => {
  t.is(Duration(1), "in just 1 minute", "testing 1 minute");
  t.is(Duration(30), "in just 30 minutes", "testing 30 minute2");
  t.is(Duration(60), "in just 1 hour.", "testing 1 hour");
});

test("Test Duration invalid", (t) => {
  t.not(Duration(1), "in just 1 minutes", "This should fail...");
});
```

### `src/Time.mjs`

```js
const Duration = (minutes) => {
  const oneMinute = 1;
  const minutesInAnHour = 60;
  if (minutes <= oneMinute) {
    return "in just 1 minute";
  }
  if (minutes < minutesInAnHour) {
    return "in just " + minutes.toFixed(0) + " minutes";
  }
  if (minutes === minutesInAnHour) {
    return "in just 1 hour.";
  }
  const hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
  const minutesValue = Math.ceil(minutes % 60);
  const hourString = hours === 1 ? "hour" : "hours";
  const minuteString =
    minutesValue === 1
      ? `1 min`
      : minutesValue > 0
      ? `${minutesValue.toFixed(0)} mins`
      : "";
  return `${hours} ${hourString}${minuteString ? ` ${minuteString}` : ""}`;
};

export { Duration };
```

Finally, run the script:

```bash
npm run test # or
yarn test
```

The results of the tests should be printed:

```
$ yarn test
yarn run v1.22.19
$ ava

  ✔ Test Duration valid
  ✔ Test Duration invalid
  ─

  1 test passed
Done in 3.04s.
```

Comment: What can be the failed test for this? How can we write a failed test for this? 
@Mr. Polywhirl

Comment: @Gurdeep see the updated unit test